# how to find html block where is some text located with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have page and I don`t know what tags are there
but I know that the word f.e. 'Cosmos' appears in different blocks such as 'a', 'div' etc ,  but I dont know what blocks are they so i cant just use

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(text_content)
result = [a for a in soup.find_all('a') if a.text == 'Cosmos']
```

I need to collect all tags where is my defined text

Comment: Is the word `Cosmos` the **only** text in that tag? Are there any other tags in the same block (like `<div>Cosmos - <a href="...">season 1</a></div>`)?

Comment: `Cosmos` is full text in the tag or substring in the text of tag??

Comment: 'cosmos' is a part of text or full text of tag f.e. <div 'id'='style'>Cosmos is Great<div> or <a href='http://'>dkasdkagsdksdkgak cosmos kashfkjaskf</a> @MartijnPieters

Comment: @user3683587: are there other tags *next* to the text? `<div id="style">Cosmos is <i>Great</i></div>`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes they could be

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom search function:

```
def contains_cosmos(elem):
    return (
        getattr(elem, 'name', None)  # is an element, not text
        # and any NavigableText child elements contain the word Cosmos
        and any('Cosmos' in child for child in elem.children 
                if not getattr(child, 'name', None))
    )

cosmos_elements = soup.find_all(contains_cosmos)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <html><body>
... <div>The Cosmos is <i>Bright</i></div>
... <ol>
...   <li><a href="...">Cosmos - Season 1</a></li>
...   <li>Episode 1: <a href="..."><b>Cosmos</b> - ...</a></li>
... </ol>
... </body></html>
... ''')
>>> def contains_cosmos(elem):
...     return (
...         getattr(elem, 'name', None)  # is an element, not text
...         # and any NavigableText child elements contain the word Cosmos
...         and any('Cosmos' in child for child in elem.children 
...                 if not getattr(child, 'name', None))
...     )
... 
>>> soup.find_all(contains_cosmos)
[<div>The Cosmos is <i>Bright</i></div>, <a href="...">Cosmos - Season 1</a>, <b>Cosmos</b>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium:

```
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(), "' + text + '")]')
```

now you could iterate on elemnts and get tags names

```
    for e in elements:
        e.tag_name
```

Whats more if you want know parent of this element could just use e.parent

You could read more at:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement